# Spawn object with custom script with Unity Network

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, spawning

I have a PlayerPref that spawn more objects in OnStartLocalPlayer().
So in OnStartLocalPlayer() it call Command(assume that called on server) that instantiate GameObject and setup some values of its scripts. At the end it calls SpanWithClientAuthority()...
The thing is that on owner client and on server those script tweeks are correct, but on all other clients it lost all that settings(ex. gameobject ref etc). What do I do wrong?

Once more in nutshell: playerPref GO must have ref list of several other objects, and those objects must have ref to that playerPref GO. (making them part of playerPref GO is not a solution).

Comment: You created a script called `PlayerPref`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need the references to be set across all clients who have the same game object. `[Command]`'s are for client to server. What you need is a `[ClientRpc]`. Make the `OnStartLocalPlayer()` call a `[ClientRpc]` function, in that function (ex: `RpcSetRefs()`) set the references you need each client to have.